# A question on Pixley-Roy topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $R$ be Real line and let $F[R]$ be $\{x\subset R:\text{is finite}\}$ with [Pixley-Roy topology.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170582/try-to-have-an-intuitional-impress-of-a-special-topological-space)

Definition of Pixley-Roy topology is this: Basic neighborhoods of $F\in F[R]$ are the sets
$$[F,V]=\{H\in F[R]; F\subseteq H\subseteq V\}$$
for open sets $V\supseteq F$, see e.g. [here](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v03/tp03111s.pdf).

**Is it submetrizable?**

Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the Pixley-Roy space in question; then $\mathscr{F}$ is submetrizable.

If $U\subseteq\Bbb R$ is open, let $U^+=\{F\in\mathscr{F}:F\cap U\ne\varnothing\}$ and $U^-=\{F\in\mathscr{F}:F\subseteq U\}$. If $F\in U^-$, then $F\in[F,U]\subseteq U^-$, and if $F\in U^+$, then $F\in[F\cap U,\Bbb R]\subseteq U^+$, so $U^-$ and $U^+$ are open in $\mathscr{F}$. Let $$\mathscr{S}=\{U^-:U\text{ is open in }\Bbb R\}\cup\{U^+:U\text{ is open in }\Bbb R\}\;;$$ clearly $\mathscr{S}$ is a subbase for a topology $\tau$ coarser than the Pixley-Roy topology on on $\mathscr{F}$. In fact $\tau$ is easily seen to be the [Vietoris topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198777/what-is-the-generating-set-of-the-vietoris-topology) on $\mathscr{F}$. It’s well-known that if $X$ is metrizable, the Vietoris topology on the space $\mathscr{K}(X)$ of non-empty compact subsets of $X$ is metrizable; a proof can be found in [this PDF](http://www.unomaha.edu/logic/teaching/ISTopology/sec25.pdf). $\langle\mathscr{F},\tau\rangle$ is a subspace of $\mathscr{K}(\Bbb R)$ with the Vietoris topology, so $\langle\mathscr{F},\tau\rangle$ is metrizable, and $\mathscr{F}$ is submetrizable.

Comment: Does this mean that if $X$ is metrizable, then $\mathscr F[X]$ is submetrizable?

Comment: @Paul: The same argument should work, yes.

Comment: Thanks Brain. If I could ask more, does there exists such kind space which is not submetrizable?

Comment: @Paul: I don’t know. My guess is that there is, but I don’t know one off the top of my head.